# pd.to_numeric ignore non numeric values

Tags: python, pandas

I try to convert a column into numeric values (int) where this is possible.
Here is a example:

```
    >>>s = pd.Series(["8", 6, "7.5", 3, "somestring"])
    >>>s
    0      8
    1      6
    2    7.5
    3      3
    4    somestring
    dtype: object
```

the documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) gives me following options:

```
    >>> pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
    0     8.0
    1     6.0
    2     7.5
    3     3.0
    4    NaN
    dtype: float64
```

what i would like to get as output is:

```
   0     8.0
   1     6.0
   2     7.5
   3     3.0
   4    somestring
```

so basically it should ignore non numeric values but convert everything else. 
if i use the errors='ignore' option s stays unchanged.
I was thinking about indexing all numeric values but can not pin down a solution. 
Thank you!

Comment: As the answers have shown this can be done, but maybe your data-layout needs some rethinking if you need columns with mixed data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not recommended, because get again mixed strings with numeric, but possible with [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
s1 = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').combine_first(s)
#alternative solution
#s1 = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').fillna(s)
print (s1)
0             8
1             6
2           7.5
3             3
4    somestring
dtype: object

print (s1.apply(type))
0    <class 'float'>
1    <class 'float'>
2    <class 'float'>
3    <class 'float'>
4      <class 'str'>
dtype: object
```

You are right, `ignore` parameter not working:

```
print (pd.to_numeric(s, errors='ignore').apply(type))
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'int'>
2    <class 'str'>
3    <class 'int'>
4    <class 'str'>
dtype: object
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

#### [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) + [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.update.html)

You can update your series with numeric values:

```
s = pd.Series(["8", 6, "7.5", 3, "somestring"])
s.update(pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce'))

print(s.apply(type))

0    <class 'float'>
1    <class 'float'>
2    <class 'float'>
3    <class 'float'>
4      <class 'str'>
dtype: object
```